Problem with Azure LogicApp the trigger "New email arrives in shared box (V2)" doesn't find attachments
I upgraded the version of outlook trigger "When new email arrives in shared box" in azure logicapp from v1 to v2 but i'm having an issue with the new version of  where it's not finding attachments, and doesn't work properly with attachments of format .msg. Is there a way to use this trigger to find attachments, including those of type .msg and .eml?
Thank you.
tested getAttachments outlook action but i didn't understand how to use it.


where it's not finding attachments, and doesn't work properly with attachments of format .msg.

Yes, this is a known limitation. According to Microsoft-Document, it says:
Extension types such as EML, MSG and ICS are ignored or currently skipped when triggered .
Even, I have observed the same:
Not only trigger , but when called attachments separately using message id:

Output:
Not recognized:


